# How can I add a transparent lock screen in Raspbian/Pixel

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, screen-lock

I want to use my Raspberry Pi as a very simple uptime dashboard and have a specific Web page showing up all the time. For practical security purposes though, I'd like to have a lock so someone can't change stuff while I'm away.

Is there a way to have a "transparent lock screen" or something similar? Mr Google pointed me to `xlock` but that doesn't seem to be available for raspbian/pixel.

Comment: For those wondering, you can call `dm-tool lock` from the Terminal to lock the Pi.

Answer (score 1):

here is an all-black lockscreen

```
sudo apt-get install light-locker
/usr/bin/light-locker-command
```

logout and login again

command to lock screen:

```
/usr/bin/light-locker-command -l
```

you can bind that to a key for example